# How to output a single DOM Node including global namespace definitions

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have a DOM-Document and I extract a certain node using XPath. After that I want to serialize that node to XML. I am using the following code:

```java
TransformerFactory
        .newInstance()
        .newTransformer()
        .transform(new DOMSource(node),
                new StreamResult(getOutputStream()));
```

This works in a simple document, but consider the following document:

```xml
<xml xmlns:foo="...">
  <bar foo:bar="xyz" />
</xml>
```

In this case if I want to serialize the node "bar", then the code above breaks, because the transformer says:

> Namespace for prefix 'foo' has not been declared

How can I get the transformer to copy the namespace definitions into the new document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `DocumentBuilderFactory` to be namespace aware.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

Comment: What does TransformerFactory have to do with DocumentBuilderFactory in this case?

Comment: What i meant is that question did not necessarily mean that the aforementioned XML document came from DocumentBuilderFactory. It might have originated from a SAAJ's SOAPBody, for example, in which case your answer is not helping anyhow.

Comment: Whichever method you use to obtain the Document object make sure it is namespace aware